# XML template in Java

Tags: java, xml, templates

I need to generate `XML` and they differ only in the values, that the tags contain.

Is it possible to create a template `XML` and then write only the values each time? (I do not want to go the `JAXB` way as these are small `XML`s and are not worth creating objects for them).

Is this a good approach?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the XML file to be produced is small, simple and mostly consistent in format, I tend to buck the trend: I simply create and write a text string.

```
writer.out.format("<?xml version='1.0'><root><tag1>%s</tag1></root>", value1)
```

kinda thing.

Comment: Java doesn't stop you from doing this with a String of practically any length. For sanity's sake, though, I would set a limit at about 20 lines of output text, or perhaps 20 tags.

Comment: FYI, the trend Carl mentions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034611/whats-so-bad-about-building-xml-with-string-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

You can use [freemarker](http://www.freemarker.org/index.html) or [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) for templating in java -- or even just add PHP tags to a sample XML to generate from a template.

I think as a general rule, though, once you start conditionally adding elements or attributes, or looping to generate multiples, you're better of generating your XML -- though I agree sometimes getting it into a format you want (not what the generator wants) is sometimes a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you are against jaxb (which I have yet to use), I wish to recommend a comparable way to do this with [Apache's XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/).

This requires you to use an xml schema - but from my experience it worth it...

Comment: You can also generate an XML Schema from an example with XMLBeans using inst2xsd http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd