# NSData / Encoding issue : why won't I read all the characters correctly?

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I'm using an `ASP` request returning a `XML` file containing some latin characters.
By using this code :

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.my-link.asp"]];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

I read almost every char of the file correctly. Almost, because some of them are replaced by this char : ¿. I'm talking about the bullet `(•, 8226)` and the right single quotation mark `(’, 8217)`, but I bet I'm going to have some issues with other unusual chars.

My `XML` prefix is `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`. I wonder if there is a problem with my `XML` file or with my code, and how to solve it.

Comment: Are you sure the response is actually in 'ISO-8859-1', and that it's not just the xml-declaration stating that it is?

Comment: If the file really is in `ISO-8859-1`, it can't contain the bullet or right single quotation mark unless they are quoted `&#8226;` and `&#8217;`, because they don't exist in `ISO-8859-1`. However i think they exist in Microsoft's variant `Windows-1252`.

Most likely the code generating the XML is not using a proper method for serializing the XML, or its conflating `ISO-8859-1` and `Windows-1252`. It's probably just concatenating strings or some such, which is a huge no-no.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034611/whats-so-bad-about-building-xml-with-string-concatenation

Comment: I just tried to save the XML result file with TextWrangler and Latin 1 encoding, and I got these errors repeatedly for every char : `untitled text:1: The character “’” (unicode 0x2019) cannot be represented in the “Western (ISO Latin 1)” encoding`

Comment: So use UTF-8 instead. And make sure you use a proper method of generating XML. `"<tag>"+escape(value)+"</tag>"` just doesn't cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UTF-8` instead of `ISO-8859-1` solved it.