# Stringify an entire Java class source code

Tags: java

I have a java class whose source code I have to send to a client. I want to send the source as a string / json / embedded into an xml. 
What would be the right way to stringify the java source code to create a valid xml / json ? Escaping quotes alone doesn't work.

Comment: have you already tried using CDATA sections inside the xml?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to "stringify" the code?

Comment: @mschenk74 Thanks, embedding in CDATA works and helps my needs.

Comment: Unless the java class contains the CDATA terminating characters. Just use an XML/JSON library for god's sake.

Comment: Is it relevant that the data is Java source, or is this just a question about XML/JSON?

Comment: try Jackson or gson  to convert Java objects to json format, for xml you can use jaxb

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I just mentioned CDATA as the next step after "Escaping quotes". I never meant it to be the perfect solution. I agree with you that this should be the job of a XML/JSON library. But I also didn't get the rationale for sending java source code via xml yet. I wonder if there is no better solution for the actual problem than sending the source code.

Comment: @Aneesh See [What's so bad about building XML with string concatenation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034611/whats-so-bad-about-building-xml-with-string-concatenation)