# How to retrieve all values of a specific attribute from sub-elements that contain this attribute?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xml.etree

I have the following XML file:

```
<main>
  <node>
    <party iot="00">Big</party>
    <children type="me" value="3" iot="A">
       <p>
          <display iot="B|S">
             <figure iot="FF"/>
          </display>
       </p>
       <li iot="C"/>
       <ul/>
    </children>
  </node>
  <node>
    <party iot="01">Small</party>
    <children type="me" value="1" iot="N">
       <p>
          <display iot="T|F">
             <figure iot="MM"/>
          </display>
       </p>
    </children>
  </node>
</main>
```

How can I retrieve all values of `iot` attribute from sub-elements of `children` of the **first** `node`? I need to retrieve the values of `iot` as a list.

The expected result:

```
iot_list = ['A','B|S','FF','C']
```

This is my current code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse("file.xml")
myroot = mytree.getroot()
list_nodes = myroot.findall('node')
for n in list_nodes:
   # ???
```

Comment: This is not well-informed XML: `<figure iot "FF"/>`. Assuming it is typo, consider fixing here in post. If not, check its source. Avoid [building XML with string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034611/whats-so-bad-about-building-xml-with-string-concatenation).

Comment: Consider Python's 3rd party, `lxml`, that supports the full XPath 1.0 and can easily return all iot attributes of children's descendants: `descendant::*/@iot`.

Comment: @Parfait: Thanks, yes, this was typo. Thanks for noticing. I've just fixed it.

Comment: The `<children>` element (in both `<node>`s doesn't have any children; `<p>` and `<li>` are its siblings.

Comment: @JackFleeting I see what you mean. I've just updated the example. Thanks.

Comment: That's better! Also - it seems you don't only want to "retrieve all values of iot attribute from **sub-elements** of children" but also from the `<children>` element itself (`A`); correct?

Comment: @JackFleeting: Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to do using the lxml library:

If the sample xml in your question represents the exact structure of the actual xml:

```
from lxml import etree
data = """[your xml above]"""
doc = etree.XML(data)

print(doc.xpath('//node[1]//*[not(self::party)][@iot]/@iot'))
```

More generically:

```
for t in doc.xpath('//node[1]//children'):
    print(t.xpath('.//descendant-or-self::*/@iot'))
```

In either case, the output should be

```
['A', 'B|S', 'FF', 'C']
```

Comment: If you know a similar solution using `xml.etree.ElementTree`, I'd appreciate.

Comment: @Fluxy - I doubt it (xpath support in ElementTree is much weaker than that of lxml), but I'll take a look.