# VBA macro to XML creating a single tag for multiple data

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am working on project with very limited vba knowledge. I am trying to pull data from sql to excel and convert that to XML by using a vba macro code to import it to the program by using built in import function.

my problem is one account have multiple contacts and in XML I want to create a single <account> ta for each account number with multiple <contact> tags under it.
tis is the VBA

```
 '   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 '   DATA DIVISION
Public Accountrow              As Integer
Public AccountCode             As String
Public CreditorCode            As String
Public AccountName             As String
Public AccountCurrency         As String
Public AccountResource         As String
Public AccountEmployee         As String
Public Classification          As String
Public Sector                  As String
Public Subsector               As String
Public Size                    As String
Public Rating                  As String
Public Source                  As String
Public TitleCode               As String
Public MVO                     As String
Public LastName                As String
Public FirstName               As String
Public Jobdescription          As String
Public CountryCode             As String
Public CountryName             As String
Public Address1                As String
Public Address2                As String
Public Address3                As String
Public PostalCode              As String
Public City                    As String
Public State                   As String
Public Phone                   As String
Public Fax                     As String
Public eMail                   As String
Public Homepage                As String
Public AccountManager          As String
Public CreditLimit             As String
Public PaymentCD               As String
Public ABN                     As String
Public Status                  As String
Public crdnr                   As String
Public BankAcc                 As String
Public freetext01              As String
Public CntType                 As String
Public CntMain                 As String
Public CntPhone As String
Public CntFax As String
Public CntMobile As String
Public CntEmail As String
Public CntPostCode As String

Sub backupConvertToXML()
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Create output file as an object in the system with the file name c:\\CREDITORS.xml
'   If this file exists, it will be overwritten without questions asked
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("D:\\Globe_Common\\Database Cutover\\XML Imports\\CREDITORS.xml", True)
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Write xml header
a.WriteLine ("\<?xml version=""1.0"" ?\>")
a.WriteLine ("\<eExact xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""                   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=""eExact-Schema.xsd""\>")
a.WriteLine ("\<Accounts\>")
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Step 1: initialize
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AccountCurrency = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(2, 2)
AccountResource = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(4, 2)
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Step 2: Write records for Creditors
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Accountrow = 12
While Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 1) \<\> Empty
CreditorCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 1)
AccountCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 1)
'       CreditorCode must be numeric but we save them as strings with leading spaces. Funny, not?
While Len(CreditorCode) \< 6
CreditorCode = " " & CreditorCode
Wend
'      AccountCode must be numeric but we save them as strings with leading spaces. Funny, not?
While Len(AccountCode) \< 20
AccountCode = " " & AccountCode
Wend

    AccountName = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 2)
    Classification = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 3)
    Sector = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 4)
    Subsector = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 5)
    Size = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 6)
    Rating = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 7)
    Source = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 8)
    TitleCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 9)
    MVO = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 10)
    LastName = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 11)
    FirstName = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 12)
    Jobdescription = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 13)
    CountryCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 14)
    CountryName = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 15)
    Address1 = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 16)
    Address2 = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 17)
    Address3 = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 18)
    PostalCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 19)
    City = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 20)
    State = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 21)
    Phone = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 22)
    Fax = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 23)
    eMail = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 24)
    Homepage = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 25)
    AccountResource = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 26)
    CreditLimit = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 27)
    PaymentCD = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 28)
    ABN = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 29)
    Status = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 30)
    crdnr = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 1)
    BankAcc = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 32)
    freetext01 = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 33)
    CntType = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 34)
    CntMain = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 35)
    CntPhone = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 36)
    CntFax = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 37)
    CntMobile = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 38)
    CntEmail = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 40)
    CntPostCode = Worksheets("Accounts").Cells(Accountrow, 41)



    Call WriteRecord(a)
    Accountrow = Accountrow + 1
Wend

'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'   Step 3: End file
'   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
a.WriteLine ("\</Accounts\>")
a.WriteLine ("\</eExact\>")
a.Close
End Sub

Private Sub WriteRecord(ByVal a As Object)
Dim LongText As String
'   Type = "S" means "Supplier"!
a.WriteLine (" \<Account code=""" & AccountCode & """ status=""" & Status & """ type=""S""\>")
a.WriteLine ("  \<Name\>" & AccountName & "\</Name\>")
a.WriteLine ("  \<Phone\>" & Phone & "\</Phone\>")
a.WriteLine ("  \<Fax\>" & Fax & "\</Fax\>")
a.WriteLine ("  \<Email\>" & eMail & "\</Email\>")
a.WriteLine ("  \<HomePage\>" & Homepage & "\</HomePage\>")

a.WriteLine ("  <Contacts>")
a.WriteLine ("   <Contact default=""" & CntMain & """ gender=""" & MVO & """ status=""A"">")
a.WriteLine ("    <LastName>" & LastName & "</LastName>")
a.WriteLine ("    <FirstName>" & FirstName & "</FirstName>")
a.WriteLine ("    <Title code=""" & TitleCode & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("    <Addresses>")
a.WriteLine ("     <Address type=""" & CntType & """ desc="""">")
a.WriteLine ("      <AddressLine1>" & Address1 & "</AddressLine1>")
a.WriteLine ("      <AddressLine2>" & Address2 & "</AddressLine2>")
a.WriteLine ("      <AddressLine3>" & Address3 & "</AddressLine3>")
a.WriteLine ("      <PostalCode>" & CntPostCode & "</PostalCode>")
a.WriteLine ("      <City>" & City & "</City>")
a.WriteLine ("      <State code=""" & State & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("      <Country code=""" & CountryCode & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("     </Address>")
a.WriteLine ("    </Addresses>")

a.WriteLine ("      <Phone>" & CntPhone & "</Phone>")
a.WriteLine ("      <Fax>" & CntFax & "</Fax>")
a.WriteLine ("      <Mobile>" & CntMobile & "</Mobile>")
 a.WriteLine ("  <Email>" & CntEmail & "</Email>")

a.WriteLine ("   </Contact>")
a.WriteLine ("  </Contacts>")


a.WriteLine ("  <Manager number=""" & AccountResource & """>")
a.WriteLine ("  </Manager>")

a.WriteLine ("  <Creditor number=""" & crdnr & """ code=""" & AccountCode & """>")
a.WriteLine ("   <Currency code=""" & AccountCurrency & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("   <SecurityLevel>10</SecurityLevel>")
a.WriteLine ("    <BankAccounts>")
a.WriteLine ("      <BankAccount code=""" & BankAcc & """  default=""" & "1" & """>")
a.WriteLine ("      <BankAccountType code=""" & "DEF" & """ checktype=""" & "N" & """>")
a.WriteLine ("      <Description>" & "Default bank account type" & "</Description>")
a.WriteLine ("      </BankAccountType>")
a.WriteLine ("      <Currency code=""" & "AUD" & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("    </BankAccount>")
a.WriteLine ("  </BankAccounts>")
a.WriteLine ("   <CreditLine>" & CreditLimit & "</CreditLine>")
a.WriteLine ("   <VATNumber>" & ABN & "</VATNumber>")
a.WriteLine ("  </Creditor>")
a.WriteLine ("  <VATFixed>0</VATFixed>")
a.WriteLine ("  <VATLiability>L</VATLiability>")
a.WriteLine ("  <PaymentCondition code=""" & PaymentCD & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("  <CompanySize code=""" & Size & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("  <CompanyOrigin code=""" & Source & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("  <CompanyRating number=""" & Rating & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("  <AccountCategory code=""" & Classification & """/>")
a.WriteLine ("  <FreeFields>")
a.WriteLine ("    <FreeTexts>")
a.WriteLine ("      <FreeText number=""" & "1" & """>" & freetext01 & "</FreeText>")
a.WriteLine ("    </FreeTexts>")
a.WriteLine ("  </FreeFields>")
a.WriteLine (" </Account>")

End Sub
```

this is screen shot of the spreadsheet

[image]

and this is the screen shot of the XML

[image]

as you can see <Account code="                1042" status="A" type="S"> is repeating but I am trying to achieve that creates only one tag every time account number changes.

I hope someone can help me to resolve this as I am running out of time and I am desperate.
Thanks in advance.

tried while / if / end if / wend around the account tag but as I said I am inexperienced in vba and couldn't get the right result. Please help.

Comment: Please see this post: [What's so bad about building XML with string concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3034611/1422451) Consider using compliant DOM libraries like VBA's MSXML. And depending on your RDBMS, look into its built-in XML methods.