# Spring Boot inject property value into XML file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

first of all sorry if the question is already answered, if so, I did not find it before. I am developing a Spring boot project with Maven. The properties configuration are done via an application.properties in my classpath, as I always do in spring boot. For this project, the client needs some external dependencies which I declared in the POM and used later in my code. The thing is that this dependency is configured via a "config.xml" file. And I cannot give this config via application.properties directly because the dependency has not this option. So, the client told me they need to configure the dependency from the spring cloud / application.properties. Thats where the problem began, because I have tried everything to pass properties values from application.properties to the config.xml and nothing worked.
Its even possible in Spring boot to dynamically inject properties into some .xml file?
This is my application.properties:

```
config.xml.active = true
config.xml.url = someurl
config.xml.user= someuser
```

And this is my config.xml:

```
<reg-enter>
    <active>**I need the property value here**</active>
    <url>**I need the property value here**<</url>
    <user>**I need the property value here**<</user> 
</reg-enter>
```

Comment: No you cannot. Your only option is to dynamically generate the XML and feed that to the library (if at all possible) if that isn't possible then it simply cannot be done and you have to find another way of configuring the library.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create this `config.xml` at startup using some templating mechanism. If XML is small and static (aside of placeholder values) you can even use string formatter. If you need more sophisticated solutions you can consider Apache Velocity.

Similar question is here: [XML template in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680175/xml-template-in-java)

Comment: Yes, I tried this option too. But the downside of this is that the application needs to be redeployed everytime I need to change some of the config.xml properties. This was one of the reasons why I am asking, its not really possible to inject values directly and dynamically right? Like others properties I use in application.properties, with the goal of modifying only the properties on the cloud config server.

Comment: It depends on the library that you use. Will it update it's state after you modify the config.xml file? If yes, you can recreate the file when you need changes from your code instead of restarting. If not, you can look if library has internal API to modify those values at runtime. I can't help you with external dependency that I do not know how it works and what it is.